# SPListItem Save conflict while Update

Tags: c#, sharepoint-2010

```
(1) var list1 = web.GetList("/lists/list1");
(2) var item1 = list1.GetItemById(10001);
(3) ...
```

take breakpoint here, open item with ID = 10001 for edit, change 'Title' fields and save it. Then run code follow:

```
(4)item1[SPBuiltInFieldId.Title] = "some text";
(5)item1.Update();
```

row (5) throws save conflict exception.

How can to lock item for edit at line (3)? Or any other approach to avoid conflict?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to check the SPListItem manually

```
try
{
  var item = list.GetItemById(3);
  item["MyField"] = "FooBar";
  item.Update();
}
catch(SPException conflictEx)
{
  // handle conflict by re-evaluating SPListItem
  var item = list.GetItemById(3);
  // ..
}
```

I don't know any other mechanism atm.

Comment: it works, but i think it exist better way to lock item direct

Answer (score 2):

> **// **create a new SPWeb object for each list modification otherwise
>   we'll get Save Conflict****

from the following URL
http://platinumdogs.me/2010/01/21/sharepoint-calling-splist-update-causes-save-conflict-spexception/

exceptions

```
using (var thisWeb = featSite.OpenWeb(featWeb.ID))
        {
            try
            {
                var listUpdate = false;
                var theList = thisWeb.Lists[att.Value];

                // change list configuration
                // .....

                // commit List modifications
                if (listUpate)
                    theList.Update();
            }
            catch
            {
                // log the event and rethrow
                throw;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: good! but what that not always applicable. ex: both update places need use current SPContext.CurrentWeb

Comment: even 2 years later, your post saved my (fri)day !

Answer (score 0):

Another approach is using Linq to SharePoint, Linq to SharePoint offers you a conflict resolution mechanism

Answer (score 0):

SharePoint's LINQ provider is querying for concurrent changes when you try to save changes you've made using the SubmitChanges method.

When a conflict has been found, a **ChangeConflictException** will be thrown.

```
foreach(var notebook in spSite.Notebooks)
{
  notebook.IsTopNotebook = true;
}

try
{
  spSite.SubmitChanges(ConflictMode.ContinueOnConflict);
}
catch(ChangeConflictException ex)
{
  foreach(ObjectChangeConflict occ in spSite.ChangeConflicts)
  {
    if (((Notebook)occ.Object).Memory > 16)
    {        
      foreach (MemberChangeConflict field in occ.MemberConflicts)
      {
        if (field.Member.Name == "IsTopNotebook")
        {
          field.Resolve(RefreshMode.KeepCurrentValues);
        }
        else
        {
          field.Resolve(RefreshMode.OverwriteCurrentValues);
        }
      }
    }
    else
    {
        occ.Resolve(RefreshMode.KeepCurrentValues);
    }  
  }
  spSite.SubmitChanges();
}
```